# It is required to free the IShellFolder interface returned by SHGetDesktopFolder ? and how?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I am confused. I want to use the function `PathToPidlBind` from Jedi JCL and I see that they don't release the IShellFolder interfece reurned by `SHGetDesktopFolder` after using it. Microsoft docs says: "The calling application is responsible for eventually freeing the interface by calling its IUnknown::Release method.". I tried to use `DesktopFolder._Release` but I get access violation. I'm not sure this is what Microsoft refers to. So how this shold be done right ?

From Jedi JCL:

```
function PathToPidlBind(const FileName:String; out Folder:IShellFolder): PItemIdList;
var
  Attr, Eaten: ULONG;
  PathIdList: PItemIdList;
  DesktopFolder: IShellFolder;
  Path, ItemName: PWideChar;
begin
  Result:=nil;
  Path:=PWideChar(ExtractFilePath(FileName));
  ItemName:=PWideChar(ExtractFileName(FileName));
  if Succeeded(SHGetDesktopFolder(DesktopFolder)) then begin
    Attr:=0;
    if Succeeded(DesktopFolder.ParseDisplayName(0, nil, Path, Eaten, PathIdList, Attr)) then begin
      if Succeeded(DesktopFolder.BindToObject(PathIdList, nil, IID_IShellFolder, Pointer(Folder))) then begin
        if Failed(Folder.ParseDisplayName(0, nil, ItemName, Eaten, Result, Attr)) then begin
          Folder:=nil;
          Result:=DriveToPidlBind(FileName, Folder);
        end;
      end;
      PidlFree(PathIdList);
    end
    else Result:=DriveToPidlBind(FileName, Folder);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: On a side note, this implementation can be simplified by using `SHBindToParent()` instead of manually splitting the path and binding to each half separately. Pass the entire `FileName` without `ExtractFilePath()` to `DesktopFolder.ParseDisplayName()` to get an absolute pidl to the file, and then let `SHBindToParent()` do the splitting and binding. You would just have to `ILClone() the final relative pidl for the `Result`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

COM interfaces are reference counted, and the Delphi compiler generates code to automatically manage the reference counting for you. Each time an interface variable is assigned, `Release` is called if the variable is not nil, and `AddRef` is called if the new value is not nil. When the variable goes out of scope, `Release` is called if not nil.

So it is a mistake to manually release the way you did. You released the interface manually, and then the compiler tried to release it automatically.  You have to let the compiler do the work.

If you do wish to release an interface before it goes out of scope, assign `nil` to it:

```
DesktopFolder := nil;
```

But there is no need for you to do that in this example.

The Delphi designers don't want you to explicitly call `AddRef` and `Release`, so they named then `_AddRef` and `_Release` in order to discourage you from calling these methods directly.

Comment: So there is no need to release anything ?

Comment: Not manually for compiler-managed types, like interfaces. The compiler handles it for you.  But you can release manually if needed, which is exactly what the `Folder:=nil` statement is doing - removing a reference to the interface that `BindToObject()` had previously returned.

Comment: No. The compiler makes a call to `_Release` for you when the interface ref goes out of scope.